# Zef fails to install JSON::Fast when running in Travis with Docker

Tags: docker, travis-ci, raku, zef

I am using [this](https://github.com/JJ/test-perl6) docker container to build exercism.io exercises with Travis. My `.travis.yml` is below:

```
language:
  - minimal

services:
  - docker

install:
  - docker pull jjmerelo/test-perl6

script: docker run -t --entrypoint="/bin/sh" -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/test jjmerelo/test-perl6 -c "zef install JSON::Fast && prove -r --exec=perl6 perl6"
```

When running, Travis fails to update the p6c mirror and is unable to find JSON::Fast, thus causing my tests to fail. A snippet of the error is shown below, with the full build logged [here](https://travis-ci.org/rhthomas/exercism/builds/529409760).

```
===> Searching for: JSON::Fast
===> Updating cpan mirror: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ugexe/Perl6-ecosystems/master/cpan1.json
===> Updating p6c mirror: http://ecosystem-api.p6c.org/projects1.json
===> Updated cpan mirror: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ugexe/Perl6-ecosystems/master/cpan1.json
!!!> Failed to update p6c mirror: http://ecosystem-api.p6c.org/projects1.json
===> Updating p6c mirror: http://ecosystem-api.p6c.org/projects.json
!!!> Failed to update p6c mirror: http://ecosystem-api.p6c.org/projects.json
===> Updating p6c mirror: git://github.com/ugexe/Perl6-ecosystems.git
===> Updated p6c mirror: git://github.com/ugexe/Perl6-ecosystems.git
No candidates found matching identity: JSON::Fast
```

Is there something I'm missing in my `.travis.yml` in order to get this working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should work if you try it again / `zef update`. `JSON::Fast` is actually in the cpan ecosystem, but the cpan ecosystem itself has been having issues the last couple of days.

The p6c ecosystem not updating is an unrelated issue (since `JSON::Fast` is in the cpan ecosystem). That can be corrected by updating zef -- `zef install https://github.com/ugexe/zef.git`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps I misunderstood but I tried `zef update && zef install JSON::Fast && prove -r --exec=perl6 perl6` and it failed again still saying no candidates found.

Comment: Can you re-run that travis-ci job (which you can do in the UI without adding any new commits)? The output of your last run is showing p6c and cpan as having the same number of dists -- this makes me think it was still using the old bugged package list.

Comment: That's been failing in all my docker builds too. We need to find a solution about the p6c index.

Comment: I'm rebuilding all my Dockerfiles from the bottom to use the new zef. Thanks, @ugexe

Comment: Thanks both, it all seems to be [working](https://travis-ci.org/rhthomas/exercism/builds/529692914) fine now! Build time is much faster than before, where I was installing `moar` every time!

Comment: @FlamingSquirrel I've uploaded a new version anyway, with the new rakudobrew and the new zef. If you download it now, it should be even better :-)